# How to disable button in Nativedroid(v0.2.2)?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, nativedroid

Button created from anchor tag is not disabled. I have tried by following:

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain" id="listDownViewSubProject">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
         <legend style="text-transform:none;">SubProjects:</legend>
         <a href="#"  data-role="button" id='btnSubProject' class="ui-disabled" data-icon='circle-arrow-down' data-iconpos='right'   style="text-transform:none;" >Select the SubProject</a>
    </fieldset>
</li>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try `disabled` attribute

```
<a href="#"  data-role="button" id='btnSubProject' data-icon='circle-arrow-down' data-iconpos='right'   style="text-transform:none;" disabled>Select the SubProject</a>
```

Comment: are you testing for nativedroid(v0.2.2)?

Comment: How come it is not working in my case? Have you tried according to my code?

Comment: i have defined button outside the listview, it is working, but inside the listview enclosed by fieldset, it is not working..

Comment: I've copied your code from the question, put it inside a div with `data-role='content'` and tested with disabled attribute.